# Extracting key-value pair from PostGreSQL jsonb column?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, extract

I have a postgresql database in which I have a column that contains a `jsonb` object.

I've come accross a situation where I need to extract a single key-value pair from my json object. I have currently no idea and have been unable to find any examples of how this is done.

I have the following table:

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | did | timestamp | data | db_timestamp |
----------------------------------------------
```

The data column is my json object and one examples of what it contains is:

```
{"n": 336372148490, "ac": 22.0, "al": 119.0, "be": 346.3, "la": 55.69707492, "lo": 12.58713834, "sa": 5, "sp": 2.6100767, "provider": "gps"}
```

So what I want to do is to write a query in which I look for a single key-value pair. I Currently have the following query,

```
SELECT data WHERE did = '357139052424715' and timestamp < 1466642640000
```

I want to extract a single key-value pair. How do I change the above query to extract `"la": 55.69707492` only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this as:

```
SELECT data->>'la' WHERE did = '357139052424715' and timestamp < 1466642640000
```

For more examples see:

http://clarkdave.net/2013/06/what-can-you-do-with-postgresql-and-json/

Comment: Can I do comparisons with this data as well?

Such as `SELECT data->>'la' WHERE did = '357139052424715' and timestamp < 1466642640000 and data->>'la' = <some-value>`?

Comment: Yes that is how you would filter

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed!